# How to read hierarchical data in MySQL using self-joins?

Tags: php, mysql, self-join

I have a table called "offers"; this is my structure:

```
|  id   | rep_id |
------------------
| 25704 | 25060  |
| 25060 | 24419  |
| 24419 | 23785  |
| 23785 |  NULL  |
```

Lets start with offer.id 23785 (the last row), it is the first offer therefore the repost id (rep_id) is NULL, after one day 23785 this will be reposted with a new id, this time it is 24419 and I know that it was 23785 and that 24419 will be 25060 and so on.

Now, my task is to call any of the above id's and identify how many times the offer has been reposted and to list all. For example if I say that I want to know how many times 25060 has reposted, it should result all the above id's because in a weird way they are connected, but I don't know how to tell MySQL that they are connected. I know this is not the best structure, but this is all I have.

My query:

```
SELECT go1.id, go1.rep_id
            FROM offers go1
            JOIN offers go2
            ON go2.rep_id = go1.rep_id
            WHERE go1.rep_id = 24419 OR go1.id = 24419
```

My result:

```
|  id   | rep_id |
------------------
| 25060 | 24419  |
| 24419 | 23785  |
```

Wanted result:

```
|  id   | rep_id |
------------------
| 25704 | 25060  |
| 25060 | 24419  |
| 24419 | 23785  |
| 23785 |  NULL  |
```

P.S. If MySQL can't do this alone, how will PHP do this?

Comment: can you post your output in a table format

Comment: I updated my post, i hope that what i said makes sense.

Comment: Phew, that's a bit confusing. You've not really described _what_ you are doing. Is "offer" a user? What is a "repost"? Why does the `id` change if an offer is reposted? I can see the hierarchical nature of the data, and this will become very hard to query very quickly. If your thing that is being reposted can maintain the same id, and then another table is used to describe its (re)postings, then your queries will be much easier, I think.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit confusing. Lets sort it a bit. Offer is a product can be anything so is a offer. xD A "repost" is when a "offer" is posting itself again and again until i tell it to stop from php. I don't know why the `id` is changed, this is how it was made and now i just need to work with what i have. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with MySQL query. No need to use PHP for this:

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    rep_id  
FROM(
    SELECT
        @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := Id FROM posts WHERE rep_id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r :=23785, @l := 0) vars,posts m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
JOIN posts T2
    ON T1._id = T2.Id
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
```

OUTPUT

```
|    ID | REP_ID |
|-------|--------|
| 25704 |  25060 |
| 25060 |  24419 |
| 24419 |  23785 |
| 23785 |      0 |
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

Take a look at this

```
 (SELECT @r :=23785, @l := 0) vars,
```

You just need to provide starting id as i have provided `23785`

With id `25060`

OUTPUT

```
|    ID | REP_ID |
|-------|--------|
| 25704 |  25060 |
| 25060 |  24419 |
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

More details about how this works [can be found here](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/).

If you want to provide some middle id then use this query

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM (
    (
    SELECT 
        num,    
        Id, 
        rep_id  
    FROM(
        SELECT
            @r AS _id,
            (SELECT @r := Id FROM posts WHERE rep_id = _id) AS parent_id,
            @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM
        (SELECT @r :=25060, @l := 0) vars,posts m
    WHERE @r <> 0) T1
    JOIN posts T2
        ON T1._id = T2.Id
    GROUP BY Id
    ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC
    ) UNION (
    SELECT 
        num,
        Id, 
        rep_id  
    FROM(
        SELECT
            @r AS _id,
            (SELECT @r := MAX(rep_id) FROM posts WHERE Id = _id) AS parent_id,
            @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
        FROM
        (SELECT @r :=25060, @l := 0) vars,posts m
        WHERE @r <> 0) T1
    JOIN posts T2
        ON T1._id = T2.Id
    GROUP BY Id
    ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC )
)l 
ORDER BY num
```

#### SQL Fiddle Demo

OUTPUT

```
| NUM |    ID | REP_ID |
|-----|-------|--------|
|   1 | 25704 |  25060 |
|   2 | 25060 |  24419 |
|   3 | 24419 |  23785 |
|   4 | 23785 |      0 |
```

Comment: hmmm, almost there. Can you make the output of 25060 the same as the ouput of 23785? The thing is: whenever i call one of those `id`'s it should give me the same output that it gave you at 23785

Comment: what do you mean by `the same as the ouput of 23785`? Can you explain.

Comment: The thing is that i need to list them all: if i call `25704`, `25060`, `24419` or `23785` i should get the same output as the starting id. I added `Wanted result` in my first post just in case i didn't explain right. thanks

Comment: @halfer you can see [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/)

Comment: @ion this solution goes from bottom to top. If you provide any middle value it will consider it as bottom value from table and start searching to the top level

Comment: Thanks, I've edited that into the question. In general, if you can add even just a sentence of what supplied code is doing, it helps, especially in the case of external link breakage (+1).

Comment: @raheelshan is there a way for me the to get all the values when calling a middle value with this structure? or should i just give up on this?

Comment: Thats all i needed, Great job @raheelshan